How to learn Sanskrit (free to learn as no payment mode is supported from my country)
I want to learn sanskrit online to understand Purans, Mahabharat, Ramayan, Gita and finally Veda.
I want to develop all the skills like Reading, Writing, Vyakarana etc. And I can give only few minutes daily. Can someone provide me online and direct link that requires no purchase? I also got the playslist, Is it good for developing all the skill in Sanskrit as I mentioned above? Please help me

